# I can not get Google Analytics to send commerce data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I rewrote this post to be clearer and to simplify the problem that I am having.

I am trying to get e-commerce data to send to Google Analytics. I am using the most basic set up to send one test transaction based on their example setup.

Google tag manager is showing the transaction, but it is not making it to the Google Analytics dashboard Conversions > Ecommerce > Overview

I have enabled Ecommerce under view in the admin panel, but no data? This is probably something simple - but I can't find it. (sample GA ID, using the proper ID in my code and the pages are tracking fine in the dashboard, just no Ecommerce data)

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('require', 'ecommerce');

console.log('order placed');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
      'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
      'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
      'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
    });


ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
      'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
      'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
      'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
      'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
    });


ga('ecommerce:send');

ga('ecommerce:clear');
```

Comment: How long did you wait to check your standard reports? You need to wait up to 24 hours for data to show up in your reports. Also, did you verify the hit with GA Debugger or in your network console?

Comment: That was it - Thank you!